# Select all records which are between certain time?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite

I am trying to get all records from the table where the time is between 09:30:00 and 15:30:00

I have the timestamp column as:

```
yyyy-mm-dd HH:MM:SS
```

The below returns an empty dataframe:

```
sta = 'SELECT * FROM bnffut WHERE timestamp BETWEEN "09:15:00" and "15:30:00"'

df = pd.read_sql(sta,conn)
```

This one gives me a all records:

```
sta = 'SELECT * FROM bnffut WHERE timestamp >= "09:15:00"'
df = pd.read_sql(sta,conn)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `timestamp` column contains both date and time and you can't compare it to time only.
 Use [`SUBSTR()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html#substr) to extract only the time from `timestamp`:

```
sta = 'SELECT * FROM bnffut WHERE SUBSTR(timestamp, 12) BETWEEN "09:15:00" and "15:30:00"'
```

Another way to extract the time part is with the use of the function [`TIME()`](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
sta = 'SELECT * FROM bnffut WHERE TIME(timestamp) BETWEEN "09:15:00" and "15:30:00"'
```

Answer (score 1):

For post filtering using `pandas`, you can use the [`DataFrame.between_time`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.between_time.html) method. This requires [`DatatimeIndex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html) so, first [`set_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.21/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) to your timestamp column:

```
df.set_index('timestamp').between_time("09:15:00", "15:30:00")
```

Comment: Thanks! But I am looking to straight away select less data. :)